# How do I exclude directories from an rsync that exist on both servers?

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

Here's my file structure:

```
Server_A                  Server_B
==============            ==============
/path/dir1/               /path/dir1/
           logA.txt                  logA.txt
           logB.txt                  logB.txt
/path/dir2/               /path/dir2/
           fileC.txt                 fileC.txt
           fileD.txt                 fileC.txt
```

I need to rsync path/dir2 from server A to B, but not path/dir1.

My rsync command looks like this:

```
rsync -arv --exclude '/dir1' /path/ root@server_b:/path
```

But every time I run it the result shows dir1 in the print out:

```
sending incremental file list
./
dir1/
dir1/logA.txt
dir1/logB.txt
sent 52147 bytes  received 23342 bytes  14405.50 bytes/sec
total size is 215619123  speedup is 2851.02
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced that you've accurately transcribed the commands you're running.  If I have a directory `/tmp/src` that looks like this:

```
/tmp/src/
/tmp/src/dir1
/tmp/src/dir1/file1
/tmp/src/dir1/file2
/tmp/src/dir2
/tmp/src/dir2/file1
/tmp/src/dir2/file2
```

I can sync it to another server -- and exclude `/tmp/src/dir1` -- like this:

```
rsync -av --exclude=/dir1 /tmp/src/ server:/tmp/dst/
```

And the run looks like this:

```
sending incremental file list
created directory /tmp/dst
./
dir2/
dir2/file1
dir2/file2
```

This appears to exactly match what you've described in your question.  I'm using rsync version 3.0.8.  I would advise examining both your actual rsync command line and the filesystem closely.  If you don't see anything obvious, can you post the *actual* command you're runing, along with a top level directory listing (unless it's huge)?